# Programmatically issuing a Kubernetes certificate

Tags: kubernetes, client-certificates, kubernetes-apiserver

I was able to manually create a certificate:

1. I created a csr file
2. I created and applied a `CertificateSigningRequest` k8s resource
3. I approved the request using

```sh
kubectl certificate approve <name>
```

4. I extracted the certificate from the `CertificateSigningRequest`'s `status.certificate` field.

Now I want to repeat the process programmatically. I'm using the `@kubernetes/client-node` npm package for this purpose.

I'm able to create and apply the `CertificateSigningRequest` resource:

```js
const csrResource = await adminCertApi.createCertificateSigningRequest({
    metadata: {
        name: 'my.email@my.company.com',
    },
    spec: {
        request: csrBase64,
        signerName: 'kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client',
        usages: [
            'client auth'
        ],
    },
});
```

But then I get stuck trying to approve the request (trying to follow the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#approval-rejection-api-client)). I tried several variations that look like this:

```js
csrResource.body.status.conditions = [
    {
        message: 'Approved by CWAdmin GraphQL Lambda function',
        reason: 'ApprovedByCWAdmin',
        type: 'Approved',
    }
];
const response = await adminCertApi.patchCertificateSigningRequest('my.email@my.company.com', csrResource.body, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/strategic-merge-patch+json' } });
```

Unfortunately, this does not update the `status.conditions` field. Even if it did, what triggers the signing of the certificate? The documentation states that the `kube-controller-manager` never auto-approves requests of type `kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client`.

In other words, what is the programmatic equivalent of `kubectl certificate approve`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this bit of [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-auth/1513-certificate-signing-request/README.md#api-changes-between-v1beta1-and-v1) that helped me solve the issue:

> - `status` is required and must be `True`, `False`, or `Unknown`
> - `Approved`/`Denied` conditions can only be set via the `/approval` subresource

So I added the `status` field to the condition and changed the API call to `patchCertificateSigningRequestApproval`.

The working code now looks like this:

```js
const body = {
    status: {
        conditions: [
            {
                message: 'Approved by CWAdmin GraphQL Lambda function',
                reason: 'ApprovedByCWAdmin',
                type: 'Approved',
                status: 'True',
            }
        ]
    }
};

const response = await adminCertApi.patchCertificateSigningRequestApproval('my.email@my.company.com', body, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/strategic-merge-patch+json' } });
```

Comment: You saved my day. But just a comment, in newer version of the nodejs client, we need to add a params for `force` before the `headers` params, set it to `undefined`